# Why isn’t my Radeon RX 580 showing up in blender with pro render?

Tags: radeon, 21.10, amdgpu, blender

[image]So I have a Radeon RX 580 that I recently got and I also enabled the prorender add on for AMD RX cards but it just isn’t showing up. I am running Ubuntu 21.10. Any help is appreciated. I installed blender via `sudo apt install blender` I am running blender version 2.93.3. Here is my system info:
[image]
Before this graphics card I had a Nvidia GTX card. I removed the drivers for that.
here is the clinfo output:
[image]

Comment: Installed AMDGPU-Pro and OpenCl drivers or using the AMD Kernel open-source drivers? I had to install AMDGPU Pro drivers to get FastFlix GPU encoding to work. How is Blender installed? Snap, Flatpak, Repo, Appimage, compiled from source, tarball or Ubuntu PPA? What version you running? Can you post your system info `inxi -Fx` might help us better understand your setup. What GPU where you using before you add the RX 580? Maybe older driver are preventing that card from working. Side Note: Wait until Ubuntu 22.04.1 gets released around August to upgrade. 22.04 seems buggy for GPU drivers. Let us

Comment: Can you help me I did everything

Comment: If this is accurate, then your GPU isn't supported.  – https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html
------------------------------------------             Czar
Jun 23 at 21:24

Comment: Maybe do some more house cleaning. Did you see reference to 'driver loaded: nvidia' Install and check output of 'clinfo' what do you get as an output? That version of Blender used OpenCL and version 3.0 for AMD uses HIP for rendering. Try this : You could make a persistent live Ubuntu USB drive and SNAP (or however you like to) install Blender with AMDPRO and OpenCL drivers. If it works then you know Nvidia/Nouveau is causing rendering issues. – 
                            ---------             Czar
Jun 23 at 21:39

Comment: I had to move my answer to comment section.             Is your GPU even supportted?            I think you might be having issue with AMD opencl drivers. Where you able to install the AMD OpenCL drivers? What did 'clinfo' output show? Does OpenCL now show up on 'inxi -Fx' Old Nvidia drivers could be preventing Blender from switching completely over to AMD drivers.                      I would dual boot install a clean Ubuntu 20.04 and see if I could get it working correctly on an LTS version. You have to get AMDGPU-Pro/OpenCL working correctly to get gpu acceleration.